# Open XML SDK HtmlToWord Styles not applying

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, styles, openxml-sdk

**HTML File:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
      <style>
          @font-face {
        font-family: Wingdings;
        panose-1: 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    }

     @font-face {
        font-family: SimSun;
        panose-1: 2 1 6 0 3 1 1 1 1 1
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "Cambria Math";
        panose-1: 2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: Calibri;
        panose-1: 2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: Verdana;
        panose-1: 2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: Tahoma;
        panose-1: 2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "MS PGothic";
        panose-1: 2 11 6 0 7 2 5 8 2 4
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "\@SimSun";
        panose-1: 2 1 6 0 3 1 1 1 1 1
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "\@MS PGothic"
    }

    div.MsoNormal,
    li.MsoNormal,
    p.MsoNormal {
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    h2 {
        mso-style-link: "Heading 2 Char";
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 18pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoToc1,
    li.MsoToc1,
    p.MsoToc1 {
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoToc4,
    li.MsoToc4,
    p.MsoToc4 {
        margin-top: 6pt;
        margin-right: .55in;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: .8in;
        text-indent: -.8in;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: #00f
    }

    div.MsoFootnoteText,
    li.MsoFootnoteText,
    p.MsoFootnoteText {
        mso-style-link: "Footnote Text Char";
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 7.5pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.MsoCommentText,
    li.MsoCommentText,
    p.MsoCommentText {
        mso-style-name: "Comment Text\,Annotationtext";
        mso-style-link: "Comment Text Char\,Annotationtext Char";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoHeader,
    li.MsoHeader,
    p.MsoHeader {
        mso-style-link: "Header Char";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif
    }

    div.MsoFooter,
    li.MsoFooter,
    p.MsoFooter {
        mso-style-link: "Footer Char";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif
    }

    span.MsoFootnoteReference {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        vertical-align: super
    }

    span.MsoPageNumber {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    span.MsoEndnoteReference {
        vertical-align: super
    }

    div.MsoEndnoteText,
    li.MsoEndnoteText,
    p.MsoEndnoteText {
        mso-style-link: "Endnote Text Char";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoBodyText,
    li.MsoBodyText,
    p.MsoBodyText {
        mso-style-link: "Body Text Char";
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: green;
        font-style: italic
    }

    a:link,
    span.MsoHyperlink {
        color: #00f;
        text-decoration: underline
    }

    a:visited,
    span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
        color: purple;
        text-decoration: underline
    }

    em {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoPlainText,
    li.MsoPlainText,
    p.MsoPlainText {
        mso-style-link: "Plain Text Char";
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Calibri, sans-serif
    }

    div.MsoCommentSubject,
    li.MsoCommentSubject,
    p.MsoCommentSubject {
        mso-style-link: "Comment Subject Char";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.MsoAcetate,
    li.MsoAcetate,
    p.MsoAcetate {
        mso-style-link: "Balloon Text Char";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoNoSpacing,
    li.MsoNoSpacing,
    p.MsoNoSpacing {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoRMPane,
    li.MsoRMPane,
    p.MsoRMPane {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoListParagraph,
    li.MsoListParagraph,
    p.MsoListParagraph {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: .5in;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst,
    li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst,
    p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: .5in;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle,
    li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle,
    p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: .5in;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast,
    li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast,
    p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: .5in;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    span.Heading2Char {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 2 Char";
        mso-style-link: "Heading 2";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    span.FooterChar {
        mso-style-name: "Footer Char";
        mso-style-link: Footer;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif
    }

    span.HeaderChar {
        mso-style-name: "Header Char";
        mso-style-link: Header;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif
    }

    div.MemoHeaderStyle,
    li.MemoHeaderStyle,
    p.MemoHeaderStyle {
        mso-style-name: MemoHeaderStyle;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 70.9pt;
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: inter-ideograph;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    span.BodyTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "Body Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "Body Text";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: green;
        font-style: italic
    }

    span.CommentTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "Comment Text Char\,Annotationtext Char";
        mso-style-link: "Comment Text\,Annotationtext";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.EMEAEnBodyText,
    li.EMEAEnBodyText,
    p.EMEAEnBodyText {
        mso-style-name: "EMEA En Body Text";
        margin-top: 6pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 6pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: inter-ideograph;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    span.BalloonTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "Balloon Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "Balloon Text";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.BodytextAgency,
    li.BodytextAgency,
    p.BodytextAgency {
        mso-style-name: "Body text \(Agency\)";
        mso-style-link: "Body text \(Agency\) Char";
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 7pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        line-height: 14pt;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    span.BodytextAgencyChar {
        mso-style-name: "Body text \(Agency\) Char";
        mso-style-link: "Body text \(Agency\)";
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.DraftingNotesAgency,
    li.DraftingNotesAgency,
    p.DraftingNotesAgency {
        mso-style-name: "Drafting Notes \(Agency\)";
        mso-style-link: "Drafting Notes \(Agency\) Char";
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 7pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        line-height: 14pt;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Courier New";
        color: #396;
        font-style: italic
    }

    span.DraftingNotesAgencyChar {
        mso-style-name: "Drafting Notes \(Agency\) Char";
        mso-style-link: "Drafting Notes \(Agency\)";
        font-family: "Courier New";
        color: #396;
        font-style: italic
    }

    div.NormalAgency,
    li.NormalAgency,
    p.NormalAgency {
        mso-style-name: "Normal \(Agency\)";
        mso-style-link: "Normal \(Agency\) Char";
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.TableheadingrowsAgency,
    li.TableheadingrowsAgency,
    p.TableheadingrowsAgency {
        mso-style-name: "Table heading rows \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 7pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        line-height: 14pt;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.TabletextrowsAgency,
    li.TabletextrowsAgency,
    p.TabletextrowsAgency {
        mso-style-name: "Table text rows \(Agency\)";
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 14pt;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    span.NormalAgencyChar {
        mso-style-name: "Normal \(Agency\) Char";
        mso-style-link: "Normal \(Agency\)";
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    span.CommentSubjectChar {
        mso-style-name: "Comment Subject Char";
        mso-style-link: "Comment Subject";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.Default,
    li.Default,
    p.Default {
        mso-style-name: Default;
        margin: 0;
        text-autospace: none;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: #000
    }

    div.HeadingSmPC,
    li.HeadingSmPC,
    p.HeadingSmPC {
        mso-style-name: "Heading SmPC";
        mso-style-link: "Heading SmPC Char";
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 28.35pt;
        text-indent: -28.35pt;
        line-height: 13pt;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    span.HeadingSmPCChar {
        mso-style-name: "Heading SmPC Char";
        mso-style-link: "Heading SmPC";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.C-TableText,
    li.C-TableText,
    p.C-TableText {
        mso-style-name: "C-Table Text";
        mso-style-link: "C-Table Text Char";
        margin-top: 3pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 3pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    div.C-TableHeader,
    li.C-TableHeader,
    p.C-TableHeader {
        mso-style-name: "C-Table Header";
        mso-style-link: "C-Table Header Char";
        margin-top: 3pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 3pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    span.C-TableTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "C-Table Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "C-Table Text"
    }

    span.C-TableCallout {
        mso-style-name: "C-Table Callout";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: windowtext;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        font-emphasize: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: super
    }

    div.C-TableFootnote,
    li.C-TableFootnote,
    p.C-TableFootnote {
        mso-style-name: "C-Table Footnote";
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: .1in;
        text-indent: -.1in;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    span.EndnoteTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "Endnote Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "Endnote Text";
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    span.PlainTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "Plain Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "Plain Text";
        font-family: Calibri, sans-serif
    }

    div.C-BodyText,
    li.C-BodyText,
    p.C-BodyText {
        mso-style-name: "C-Body Text";
        mso-style-link: "C-Body Text Char";
        margin-top: 6pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 6pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        line-height: 14pt;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif
    }

    span.C-BodyTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "C-Body Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "C-Body Text"
    }

    div.DocID,
    li.DocID,
    p.DocID {
        mso-style-name: DocID;
        mso-style-link: "DocID Char";
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #000
    }

    span.DocIDChar {
        mso-style-name: "DocID Char";
        mso-style-link: DocID;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #000
    }

    span.C-TableHeaderChar {
        mso-style-name: "C-Table Header Char";
        mso-style-link: "C-Table Header";
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.TitleA,
    li.TitleA,
    p.TitleA {
        mso-style-name: "Title A";
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.TitleB,
    li.TitleB,
    p.TitleB {
        mso-style-name: "Title B";
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 28.35pt;
        text-indent: -28.35pt;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.eCTD-Table-Text,
    li.eCTD-Table-Text,
    p.eCTD-Table-Text {
        mso-style-name: eCTD-Table-Text;
        margin-top: 2pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 2pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: #000
    }

    span.UnresolvedMention1 {
        mso-style-name: "Unresolved Mention1";
        color: gray;
        background: #E6E6E6
    }

    span.FootnoteTextChar {
        mso-style-name: "Footnote Text Char";
        mso-style-link: "Footnote Text";
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.Heading1Agency,
    li.Heading1Agency,
    p.Heading1Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 1 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 13.5pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.Heading2Agency,
    li.Heading2Agency,
    p.Heading2Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 2 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic
    }

    div.Heading3Agency,
    li.Heading3Agency,
    p.Heading3Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 3 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.Heading4Agency,
    li.Heading4Agency,
    p.Heading4Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 4 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic
    }

    div.Heading5Agency,
    li.Heading5Agency,
    p.Heading5Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 5 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.Heading6Agency,
    li.Heading6Agency,
    p.Heading6Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 6 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.Heading7Agency,
    li.Heading7Agency,
    p.Heading7Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 7 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.Heading8Agency,
    li.Heading8Agency,
    p.Heading8Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 8 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif
    }

    div.Heading9Agency,
    li.Heading9Agency,
    p.Heading9Agency {
        mso-style-name: "Heading 9 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    div.No-numheading2Agency,
    li.No-numheading2Agency,
    p.No-numheading2Agency {
        mso-style-name: "No-num heading 2 \(Agency\)";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic
    }

    div.No-numheading3Agency,
    li.No-numheading3Agency,
    p.No-numheading3Agency {
        mso-style-name: "No-num heading 3 \(Agency\)";
        mso-style-link: "No-num heading 3 \(Agency\) Char";
        margin-top: 14pt;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
        margin-left: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    span.No-numheading3AgencyChar {
        mso-style-name: "No-num heading 3 \(Agency\) Char";
        mso-style-link: "No-num heading 3 \(Agency\)";
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700
    }

    .MsoChpDefault {
        font-size: 10pt
    }

    @page WordSection1 {
        size: 595.35pt 842pt;
        margin: 56.7pt 56.7pt 56.7pt 56.7pt
    }

    div.WordSection1 {
        page: WordSection1
    }

    ol {
        margin-bottom: 0
    }

    ul {
        margin-bottom: 0
    }
</style>
```

LIST
        
        
    
    
        1. NAME OF THE EMPLOYEES
        USERNAME1
        
        USERNAME2

**C# Code:**

```
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
  using HtmlToOpenXml;
  void GenerateHtml2Word()
  {
     string pathToHTMLFile = @"C:\Users\User1\Downloads\SampleHTML.html";
     string filename = @"C:\Users\User1\Downloads\sampleWordDoc.docx";
     string htmlString = File.ReadAllText(pathToHTMLFile);
     byte[] htmlBytes = WordHelper.HtmlToWord(htmlString);
     File.WriteAllBytes(filename, htmlBytes);
 }
```

```
class WordHelper
{
    public static byte[] HtmlToWord(String html)
    {
        string filename = @"C:\Users\User1\Downloads\sampleWordDoc.docx";
        if (File.Exists(filename)) File.Delete(filename);

        using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
                   generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
                if (mainPart == null)
                {
                    mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                }

                HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
                Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
                converter.ParseHtml(html);
                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }

            return generatedDocument.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

In Browser, HTML file is loaded with styles (Times New Roman, Size 11) and classes correctly.

**Browser Output:**

[image]

**But after generating to word, styles are not affecting. what might went wrong?**

**Word Document after Generated:** Font Family: Calibri

[image]

I tried to change "pt" to "px" in HTML for font size.

Comment: ssuming you are using the converter from OpenXML PowerTools, I think the problem is that it does not work by setting the properties of Word styles then apply the style. AFAICS it only takes the low level properties such as point size, font name, etc. and apply them directly to the text. If so, specifying that a paragraph has class msoNormal won't do anything useful. But that's just a guess on my part after watching some of Eric White's video about on the converter. It's open source code, so you could consider modifying the code to pick up the style names and do what you need.

Comment: @jonsson I am using Open XML SDK("https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/")  nuget package not Open XML power tools

Comment: But isn't "Using HtmlToOpenXml" using an additional package? Perhaps one of the versions of html2openxml? If so, the style names it recognises seem to be set up in PredefinedSTyles.resx, and e.g. "msoNormal" is not listed there.